# Apache RewriteCond not working for static files

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost

I have two copies of the website in separate directories for different languages (Spanish and English) and the directory structure is as follows

```
+ /var/www/website
  |- es
  |- en
```

The `es` directory serves the Spanish version of the website and `en` serves the English version (default language).

The URL schema would be like

```
# English version
https://example.com/
https://example.com/en/ -> Redirects to https://example.com/

# Spanish version
https://example.com/es/
```

The static files are served from the respective directories only.

Now, I have the following `Apache2` configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The primary domain for this host
        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/website
        <Directory /var/www/website>
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride all

                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
                RewriteRule ^$ /es/ [R]

                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
                RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R]

                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^en [NC]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^es [NC]
                RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm facing a few problems with the configuration

1. `https://example.com/es/` and `https://example.com/en/` are working but static files are not loading and the URL for the static files looks like `https://example.com/image.png` which has to be `https://example.com/es/image.png` (for Spanish) and `https://example.com/en/image.png` (for English)
2. `https://example.com/en/` should be redirected to `https://example.com/` and the English website should be served, whereas the reverse is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first understand what is happening here.

With rules like this

```
RewriteRule ^$ /es/ [R]
```

you are redirecting requests to `/` to `/es/`.

Redirecting means, the server will tell the browser to go search for the content at some other place.

The browser will then send another request to `/es/`. This will not be rewritten nor redirected as there is no matching rule.

You html file apparently contains references with absolute URLs like this:

```html
<img src="/image.png" />
```

Your browser will therefore send a request for `/image.png`, which is not redirected, nor rewritten.

There are different ways how to solve that:

### 1. Update your html/code to absolute URLs with the right path

Like this:

```html
<img src="/es/image.png" />
```

That's the best solution imho. Depending on how you generate the content, there might be an option to set the base URL of the project.

#### 1b. Make the webserver do these substitution on the fly for you

You could think about whether you want apache to make these substitutions for you, e.g. using `mod_substitute`, but there might be cases you cannot catch with this approach. I would not recommend it.

### 2. Update your html/code to relative URLs

I.e.

```html
<img src="image.png" />
```

This sounds nice on first sight, but can become ugly if you're having complex page structure, e.g. `/es/foo/bar/somepage.html` would need `<img src="../../image.png" />` to reference `/es/image.png`.

It can become especially tricky if you want to serve the same content under `/es/foo` and `/es/foo/` (without redirecting one or the other). The two would need a different relative path to the image.

### 3. Rewrite requests for `/image.png`

In theory, you could let Apache rewrite requests for `/image.png` to either `/es/image.png` or `/en/image.png` depending on the accept-language header.

I would not recommend that, as it leads to strange behavior. E.g. assume a user consciously decides to visit `/en/` even though his language settings prefer Spanish. The browser would then request `/image.png` and the server would deliver - based on the language settings - the Spanish variant of the image. While the HTML shows the English content.